# Cannot Make a connection through FTP with my Windows 10 pc and android phone

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ftp, android

I can make an ftp server on my pc and my phones wont connect
I can make an ftp server on my phone, other phones and laptop connected on wifi do connect but pc doesn't.

How can i fix this?
I have tried turning off firewall, opening ports 20 and 21 on router and firewall settings but nothing worked.
Please help!

Comment: I think we might need to know a lot more about the network setup - are they both in the same address range? How are they connected to the network(is the PC wired/WiFi card?) etc.

Comment: pc is connected through an ethernet cable directly to the router. Devices have the same address range and subnet @Smock